# Does running Nexuiz gives extra pressure on Processor if you dont have external Graphics card?

Tags: graphics

Its a rather stupid question, though I want to be sure. Does having a external graphics card can lower the stress over the processor? what kind of graphics card Ubuntu supports ?

Well I'm planning to buy a graphics card for Windows 7 as I have started learning Adobe Premiere Pro. Which G card should I buy? Do i consider the card or the availability of the card drivers for Ubuntu Linux ?

If I install a Graphics card and does not install its drivers can I left it unused on Ubuntu ? I don't think theres a much need for G card on Ubuntu Though.

Comment: nVidia is a good choice as it has great support for Linux than ATI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link that others may find useful: 
Configure Graphics on Ubuntu- http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/xorg

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's driver manager probably has the driver for whichever Nvidia or ATI card you get. A quick websearch yielded [this post](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/05/29/best-graphics-card-for-ubuntu-11-04-10-10/) which mentions a few nvidia cards that should work in Ubuntu.

Windows 7 is already a few years old, so the win7 logo on the box is not a bad thing to have, and should have the drivers disc for windows 7 in the box (which is useful if you plan on using win7 with that card). A dedicated graphics card has its own GPU. The newer CPU's have built-in GPU in my understanding, mind you in theory having a dedicated graphics card would lighten the burden on the CPU for graphics rendering.